# How to solve jars conflict with different libraries?

Tags: eclipse, jar

i am using Repast Simphony in my project and its library contains many jars. meantime, i am using GeoTools and they are conflict because Repast Simphony employ geotools 2.3.3 and i want to use geotools 2.7.

the problem is i don't know how to remove some jars from the Repast Simphony. To add it, i just right click the project and have a option of **Repast Simphony** > Add Repast Simphony to this project

in the build path i can't edit that library. under the bulid path, after i press **edit** the only thing i can change is the name of the library. and in the .project file i found

```
<buildSpec>
.
.
.
<buildCommand>          <name>repast.simphony.eclipse.repast_simphony_builder</name>            <arguments>             </arguments>        </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
.
.
.
<nature>repast.simphony.eclipse.repast_simphony_nature</nature>
</natures>
```

and in the .classpath file it looks like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="REPAST_SIMPHONY_SUPPORT"/>
```

then i **suspend all validators** and remove the confilcted jars from the Repast library, however, it's not working. i can't build project due to lack of jars. so i am think about to edit some files to cross those conflict jars from the repast library, but i don't know how?

There is a “C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\repast.simphony.core_2.0.0\plugin_jpf.xml” file and “C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\repast.simphony.core_2.0.0\META-INF\ MANIFEST.MF” file. In above 2 files, all included files are list. I remove some of jars path but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the Repath library is written in a clean way, you could simply use in your code full names.and.paths for all conflicting `include` operators. If the Repath does it, too, there will be no conflicts thereafter.